# Force visual studio debugger to keep symbols after library unload

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to find leaks using Visual Studio's performance tools (VS2015) and running the program in the debugger.

When library is loaded Visual Studio loads the symbols, but when library is unloaded the symbols are gone thus I do not see the source of allocations in memory profiler.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio remember the symbols for addresses in unloaded library?

Comment: Need more details. Whose program it is, one that you are debugging? Can you modify it? What you mean by "Is there a way to make Visual Studio remember the symbols for addresses in unloaded library?"? If library is unloaded, how will it help if VS remembers locations? Could you give an example?

Comment: Please, is it possible to details what is library that mentions in your question? This Library is a Class Library Project, or an external DLL (from Nuget Package or S.O.)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why VS2015 in 2021 when VS2019 community is free ?

Comment: Our library. Can't link against it, a lot of logic is built around it being dynamically loaded. Remembering is needed for memory debugger to see potential leak locations.